# How to declare a base repository for a MappedSuperclass base type with spring data?

Tags: jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

We're having a hierarchy of entity classes where all inherit from a BaseEntity @MappedSuperclass. Is there a way to have a spring-data "base repository" that allows you to query for any BaseEntity without having to know it's type and use a specific repository?

```java
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String owner;
    // setter/getter etc...
}

@Entity
public class FooEntity extends BaseEntity {
    private String foo;
}

@Entity
public class BarEntity extends BaseEntity {
    private String bar;
}

/**
 * How to declare this base repository....
 */
public interface BaseRepository extends JpaRepository<BaseEntity, ActionPK> {
    List<BaseEntity> findByOwner(String owner);
}


@Component
public class MyService {
    @Autowired
    private BaseRepository baseRepository;

    public void doSomething() {
        // ... so that is can be used like this:
        List<BaseEntity> entities = baseRepository.findByOwner("john");
        doSomethingWith(entities);
    }
}
```

Comment: How will Spring or Hibernate know which table to query?  Sounds like what you are asking will have to go query all the tables in the system that have an owner column.

Comment: Yes you're right. The base repository would need to do multiple queries with multiple repositories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only way you could achieve this is to create a Service class that will orchestrate all the calls to your Repository classes that have an owner property.  That service call would return your list of `BaseEntity` objects.